# moving coordinate point by X meters in certain direction

Tags: mysql, postgresql, geolocation, coordinate-systems

i have a coordinate point stored in postgresql , for example 33.215, 35.124 ...I have the direction of the azimuth vector (angle from north) being 55, I wish to move the point in the direction of the azimuth by 20 meters , how can I achieve this ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Should you have installed the `PostGIS` extension, you can use [`ST_Project`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Project('POINT(35.124 33.215)'::geography, 20, radians(55.0)));
```

Comment: thanks! seems to do the job! small question, in you example, 55 is in degrees and being converted to radians, right?

Comment: was trying this example I had that we computed manually, (78.4437, -0.31399 , moving 100m , azimuth 30), our result was -78.4432, -0.313211, whereas in the above method it was -78.4432508354379 -0.319116793293144 , a difference in direction , can you please advise? thanks  (SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Project('POINT(-78.4437 -0.3199)'::geography, 100, radians(30.0)));)

Comment: @roynaufal It could be a difference in what you / the function considers as azimuth 0 degrees. See the doc in the provided link.

Comment: @roynaufal Yes, the function expects an azimuth expressed in radians